# RESET navigation - Drawer route with animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Before all, I have to precise I searched arround as for example https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1000 , https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/307 or even StackOverflow.

---

I have the following code :

```
/****  STACKNAVIGATOR 2 ****/
const HomeDrawer = StackNavigator({
   HomeDrawerstack: { screen: Home, navigationOptions: { title: 'Accueil',  } },    
  }, { initialRouteName: 'HomeDrawerstack', }    
 );

/****  STACKNAVIGATOR 3 ****/
const AddIdeaDrawer = StackNavigator({
   AddIdeaDrawerRoot: { screen: AddIdea, navigationOptions: { title: 'AddIDea',  } },    
  }, { initialRouteName: 'AddIdeaDrawerRoot', }    
 );

/****  DRAWERNAVIGATOR ****/
const DrawerRoutes = {
    HomeRoot: {
      screen: HomeDrawer, 
      navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Home',
      },
    },
    AddIdea: {
      screen: AddIdeaDrawer 
      navigationOptions: { 
        title: 'Add an idea',
      },
    },
};

const DrawerOptions = {
  initialRouteName: 'HomeRoot',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,  
  drawerWidth: 300,
}; 

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(DrawerRoutes, DrawerOptions); 


/****  STACKNAVIGATOR 1 ****/
export const Navigation = StackNavigator({  
   HomeDrawerRoot: { screen: Drawer, navigationOptions: { header: null } },    
   OtherRoot: { screen: Contacts, navigationOptions: { /** **/ } }, 
  }, { initialRouteName: 'HomeDrawerRoot', }    
 );
```

#### What I have tried

Currently, I'm trying to navigate from HomeDrawerstack to AddIdeaDrawerRoot with the StackNavigator animation and preventing the user to go back.
I have tried different solutions I have found on the different issues but any of them solve this problem.

**First try :**

`navigate('AddIdea',)}`
The app goes to AddIdea perfectly. However, the user can go back (that's normal I don't use RESET) and there is no animation. The AddIdea screen appears like that without any transition.

**Second try :**

```
NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'AddIdea',})
          ]
})
```

It doesn't work. 
The logs prints :  `There is no route defined for key AddIdea.  Must be one of: 'HomeDrawerstack'`

**Third try :**

I read on an another issue https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/#1127 which explains that the key:null was the solution. So I tried the following action :

```
NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          key: null,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'HomeDrawerRoot',
              action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AddIdea',}),
              })
          ]
 })
```

The app goes well to AddIdea. However, still  with the possibility of going back to the last page (Home) and without animation.

**Fourth try :**

```
navigate({
    routeName: 'HomeDrawerRoot',
    action: NavigationActions.navigate({ 
        routeName: 'AddIdea', action: NavigationActions.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: AddIdeaDrawerRoot
                        ]
                        })
            })
})
```

It doesn't work. Printing :  `There is no route defined for key AddIdeaDrawerRoot.  Must be one of: 'HomeDrawerstack'`

---

#### What I'm trying to do

The only thing I want is going from HomeDrawerstack (Home screen) to AddIdeaDrawerRoot (AddIdea screen). With an animation like the StackNavigator animation and preventing the user of going back. (Disable Back action).

After reading a lot of issues, I didn't find any solutions. Is it a forget of the react-navigation ? Or I'm the problem ?! Thanks in advance.

---

#### My current configuration

```
| software         | version
| ---------------- | -------
| react-navigation |  ^1.0.0-beta.11
| react-native     |  0.45.1
| node             | 7.4.0
| npm or yarn      |  0.24.5
```

Comment: The solution can be found here : https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/3593

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problems and could not find a good example app. My navigation in my app crashed the app which was very frustrating. In the end I found a good working project to base my code on: https://github.com/paraswatts/DrawerNavigatorReactNative/

This project has working navigation with both tabs and drawers with no crashes and clean code. I hope it can help you.